# How to exclude packages from SonarQube coverage overall filled by jacoco report?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, jacoco, maven-surefire-plugin

I´m using jacoco with SonarQube for coverage overall, and I´m trying to exclude some package from coverage overall, but seems does not works.
I just follow the same conf that people publish in diferents blogs, but like I said could not make it works.
Here my configuration. Do you see something wrong there?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>${jacoco.skip}</skip>
        <destFile>${jacoco.datafile}</destFile>
        <append>true</append>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/src/main/java/com/utils/**</exclude>
            <exclude>**/TibcoBrokerWrapper.java</exclude>
            <exclude>**/src/main/java/com/cosdemo/**/*</exclude>
            <exclude>**/src/main/java/com/mock/**/*</exclude>
            <exclude>**/src/main/java/com/behaviour/**/*</exclude>
            <exclude>**/src/main/java/com/behaviour/**</exclude>
            <exclude>com.utils</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set this from the UI, not in your pom. See [the docs](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreCodeCoverage) for more.

Answer (score 1):

Not use src/main/java :

```
Change :
 <exclude>**/src/main/java/com/cosdemo/**/*</exclude>
To 
<exclude>**/cosdemo/**</exclude> or  <exclude>**/cosdemo/**/*</exclude>

And
 <exclude>**/TibcoBrokerWrapper.java</exclude>
To
<exclude>**/TibcoBrokerWrapper*.class</exclude>
```

Comment: I just did that but nothing. I´m afraid the problem is I need to exclude as mention below on the UI as well. But I dont have permissions.